# JS InfiniteRotator Random Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image rotator on my website but I want the images to appear in a random order, that way the same image isn't always first.  I have the rotator working, but I do not know how to randomize it.  My code is on JS Bin here: http://jsbin.com/dogimawuli/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.1"></script>
  <script>
  $(window).load(function() {   

    var InfiniteRotator = 
  {
    init: function()
    {
        //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
        var initialFadeIn = 1000;

        //interval between items (in milliseconds)
        var itemInterval = 4000;

        //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
        var fadeTime = 50;

        //count number of items
        var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

        //set current item
        var currentItem = 0;

        //show first item
        $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

        //loop through the items        
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                currentItem = 0;
            }else{
                currentItem++;
            }
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        }, itemInterval);   
     }  
  };

  InfiniteRotator.init();

});
  </script>
  <style>
    #rotating-item-wrapper {position: relative;width: 468px;height: 60px;float: right;}
    .rotating-item {display: none;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="rotating-item-wrapper">
      <div style="width:400px;height:60px;background:red;"class="rotating-item">1</div>
      <div style="width:400px;height:60px;background:green;"class="rotating-item">2</div>
      <div style="width:400px;height:60px;background:blue;"class="rotating-item">3</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will give you your random number from 0-2 - var currentItem = Math.floor(Math.random()*numberOfItems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.0.1"></script>
  <script>
  $(window).load(function() {   
      debugger;
    var InfiniteRotator = 
  {
    init: function()
    {
        //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
        var initialFadeIn = 1000;

        //interval between items (in milliseconds)
        var itemInterval = 4000;

        //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
        var fadeTime = 50;

        //count number of items
        var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

        //set current item
        var currentItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfItems)


        //show first item
        $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

        //loop through the items        
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            nextItem = currentItem;
            while(currentItem == nextItem) {
                nextItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfItems);
            }
            currentItem = nextItem;
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        }, itemInterval);   
     }  
  };

  InfiniteRotator.init();

});
  </script>
  <style>
    #rotating-item-wrapper {position: relative;width: 468px;height: 60px;float: right;}
    .rotating-item {display: none;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="rotating-item-wrapper">
      <div style="width:400px;height:60px;background:red;"class="rotating-item">1</div>
      <div style="width:400px;height:60px;background:green;"class="rotating-item">2</div>
      <div style="width:400px;height:60px;background:blue;"class="rotating-item">3</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

basically you are looping through next random number which is not the same one as the current image, the drawback this is that some image will be "starved" until random number will select that image number.

Comment: That worked thank you.  One thing I notice is that some of the images show up more than others.  Is there anyway to set it so each image shows up an even percentage of the time?  Or is that just getting too complicated?